# Javascript multipying without using * sign

Tags: javascript

Practice Problem 1
Parameters: The function accepts two positive integers N and M.
Return Value: The function returns the product of N and M. For example, if the integers 5 and 8 are supplied to
that function, it should return the product of 5 and 8—it should return 40.
Additional
Requirements:
Do this without using the multiplication operator (*). Hint: Multiplication is just a series of addition
operations.

Comment: since you limit to positive integers, this is pretty easy...

Comment: *"Hint: Multiplication is just a series of addition operations."* - All you have to do is implement that functionality.

Comment: I can't figure out what to flag this as, but this is not a question, and StackOverflow isn't a place for "practice problems".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing or homework solving service

Answer (score 4):

```
function mult(N, M) {
    return N / (1 / M);
}
```

Comment: Note: This does not work if M = 0, but the OP specified "positive integers."

Comment: Also, probably not the "spirit" of the assignment.

Comment: Probably not, but still a useful answer. It certainly wouldn't have occurred to me to do it that way.

Comment: seems to work with zero for me...

Comment: Oh. So it does. I'm too used to Python; I assumed it would throw an exception. Forgot that Javascript has `Infinity`.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a basic excercise, I think that this answer is not expected (but maybe you'll get bonus points if you can explain it), even though it does the math without *.

```
function mult(N,M){
  var a = new Array(N);
  return a.join(""+M).split("").reduce((x,y)=>(parseInt(x)+parseInt(y)))+M
}
```

Note: This does not work for N < 3.  No time to correct it.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain it instead.

Comment: thank you sir ^_^ im just a student. and i find this hard :(

Comment: This is a basic excercise that is expected to be done with a loop,  Since SO is not intended as a site for solving homework problems I tried to give a slightly more complicated solution (and an incomplete solution in this case). Have fun discovering how to solve the original problem with a loop, *while* you look *for* the answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Look. It sounds like you're quite young so I think giving you the benefit of the doubt is alright here. So you know for the future:  Stackoverflow isn't a site that you can just drop a homework question and expect people to do the work for you.

We sometimes do help with homework questions but only if it looks like you've at least attempted to answer the question yourself, by showing us some code that you've written. If you want to use SO in the future you might find [the help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful, particularly the section on [how to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

OK, lecture over.

What the question is asking about is how to use [a simple `for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) to add some numbers together:

```
function getProduct(num1, num2) {

    // set total to zero
    // we'll be adding to this number in the loop
    var total = 0;

    // i is the index, l is the number of times we
    // iterate over the loop, in this case 8 (num2)
    for (var i = 0, l = num2; i < l; i++) {

        // for each loop iteration, add 5 to the total
        total += num1;
    }

    // finally return the total
    return total;
}

getProduct(5, 8); // 40
```